# QGIS 3.4 calculate date, add month

Tags: qgis, expression, date, calculate-values

I want to add a number of months to a date to get a new date. I have a date-field "date", an integer-field "months" and a date-field "new_date". I want to calculate the "new_date" by adding the "months" to the date. I did it with the expression: 
`"date"+  to_interval( concat (  to_string("months"), ' months'))`
For example: "date"= 2019-06-04, "months" = 12,
the result ("newd_date") is: 2020-05-29, but I want to have: 2020-06-04.
It seems that QGIS is calculating each month with 30 days. Is there a way to add the exact months?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What a shame the `to_interval` expression treats each month as 30 days!

Here's an ugly expression which will do what you want:

```
   to_date(concat(year("date")+floor((month("date")+"months"-1)/12), '-',
     right('0' || ((month("date")+"months"-1)%12+1) , 2),'-', 
     right('0' || day("date"),2)))
```

It breaks the date down into year, month and day, then uses the "months" field to add the relevant amount of years and months, then concatenates the values to make a string to convert to a date.  The `to_date` expression is very particular about the input format - the month and day must be two digits - so the `right` expressions are used to pad out single digit months/days with a leading zero.

Edit: Now working for when the new month is 12.  But this is still a naive solution which will fail when the start date is the 31st of the month and the new month has only 30 days or less.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for 12, 24, 36 months! But not for 6 month. Then the new_date ist Null. What can I do?

Comment: My bad - see updated answer, with corrected sub expression for the year part.

Comment: I was one week without internet, so I only tested now the updated answer (thank you for the update!). It is almost what I want. But what will I do with e 31st of the month?

Comment: It will try to create an impossible date, eg 30th February, 31st September and fail  - probably producing a Null.

Comment: maybe I can find a solution with `case when` for the dates wich produces a Null. I will try it...

Comment: I found a solution with `case when` but it's too long for the comment. so I will write it as answer. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of M Bain I found a solution, because the number of monthes are only 6, 12, 24 and 35. So I did i like this and choosed for the special dates the last existing date:
`case
when  day( "date")='31' and  month( "date" ) ='03' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date"), '-09-30' )  )
when  day( "date")='31' and  month( "date" ) ='05' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date"), '-11-30' )  )
when  day( "date")='29' and  month( "date" ) ='08' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date")+1, '-02-28' )  )
when  day( "date")='30' and  month( "date" ) ='08' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date")+1, '-02-28' )  )
when  day( "date")='31' and  month( "date" ) ='08' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date")+1, '-02-28' )  )
when  day( "date")='31' and  month( "date" ) ='10' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date")+1, '-04-30' )  )
when  day( "date")='31' and  month( "date" ) ='12' and "months"=6
then to_date(concat(year("date")+1, '-06-30' )  )
else
to_date(concat(year("date")+floor((month("date")+"months"-1)/12), '-',
     right('0' || ((month("date")+"months"-1)%12+1) , 2),'-',
     right('0' || day("date"),2)))
end`
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Well done for sticking with it and covering all the cases!